# Use native sdk in cross browser plugin tool

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, kango-framework

I am using [kango extension](http://kangoextensions.com/) to make cross browser plugin.
But I need to use part of **native firefox sdk**.
But I have a problem with following code:

```
var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
```

This doesn't work at all and doesn't print any error.
I added `sdk` folder from mozila sdk folder `sdkx/lib/sdk`.
I also have tried to move whole `lib` folder inside plugin but it doesn't work also.
I use native features from safari and chrome in the same way but only firefox requires this import of sdk.
What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Try this: `var {Cu} = require('chrome'); Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm'); var window = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');` if that doesnt work try `var {Cu: utils} = Components` in place of the first line